# ffmpeg how to put color overlay over video

Tags: colors, ffmpeg, overlay, opacity

I want to put a color overlay (blue, red or green or hex value) over a video giving it a Instagram filter like effect.

I think it should be in the lines of:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i "red.png" -filter_complex "blend=all_mode='screen':all_opacity=0.7" output.mp4
```

or maybe with `all_mode=overlay`

But I get an error:

```
First input link top parameters (SAR 0:1) do not match the corresponding second input link bottom parameters (SAR 1:1).
```

I also tried with `lutrgb=r=1.5`, but that didn't give it a red color (it takes the red away).

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Post the full console output of your command please.

Comment: thanks, here is gist [link](https://gist.github.com/flieks/bf79edc69c72a6faa426)

Comment: try the command in my updated answer

Comment: hi aergistal
that worked great. Thank you so much. The color is more pink but i assume this is normal when you place opacity. 
Maybe i have to use the "0xFF000050" for example like you proposed (with alpha).
Even with opacity 1 i can still see through the color overlay.

Comment: Yes, you can experiment. You can do the same using the `png` if you want. Please accept the answer if it solves your issue.

Comment: thanks for all help :)

Comment: how do i create such a color with alpha (can't find it)
0xFF00000.5 doesn't work

Comment: The png has to be same size in Pixels ?

Comment: Yes, you can scale it with a filter if needed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The two inputs must share the same dimensions and SAR. You can either use the `setsar` filter to set the same SAR or you can avoid using an image file completely by using `color`:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -f lavfi -i "color=red:s=1280x720" -filter_complex "blend=shortest=1:all_mode=overlay:all_opacity=0.7" output.mp4
```

Where `s=1280x720` is the size of the input video frame.

The [color](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Color) has the `[0x|#]RRGGBB[AA]` format.

---

Update:

If you still have issues with the input video SAR try to explicitly set it using the `setsar` filter:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -f lavfi -i "color=red:s=1280x720" \
-filter_complex "[0:v]setsar=sar=1/1[s];\
[s][1:v]blend=shortest=1:all_mode=overlay:all_opacity=0.7[out]" \
-map [out] -map 0:a output.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks aergistal, i took your code but still have the same error (SAR 0:1 and 1:1).
i also got "Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_blend_0" but this was also there previously.

Comment: aergistal, the colors don't really work. If i take blue or green it doesn't really matter. It's always "pinkish". It only gets more dark of white but colors aren't coming through. You know of solution ?

Comment: Take a look at the [blend](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#blend_002c-tblend) parameters. It has multiple modes.

Comment: thanks i found it's mode_all:overlay (not screen)
I read lavfi is equivalent of -filter_complex. Why do you seperate them? I want to combine with my other code i had but it's difficult:
-i audio.mp3 -shortest  (=> another audio)
-shortest  -t 8               (=> can only be 8sec long)
crop = 500:500            (=> crop it)

This doesn't apply the cropping:
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -f lavfi -i "color=Red:s=1280x720" -i audio.mp3 -shortest -t 8  -filter_complex "[0:v]setsar=sar=1/1[s];[s][1:v]blend=shortest=1:all_mode=overlay:all_opacity=0.7[out]; crop=500:500[out]" -map [out] -map 2:a output.mp4